# wscanf(L"%[^\n]") is inputting garbage

Tags: c, widechar

I'm making a hangman program on c using wide characters. It has to allow spaces on the words to play (which the program will detect it as an illegal character).

The important part of the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t sentence[30];
    printf("Gimme a sentence:\n");
    wscanf(L"%[^\n]", sentence); //Reading the line
    wprintf(L"Your sentence: %ls\n", sentence); //Printing the whole line

    printf("Detecting non-alphabetic wide characters"); //Detecting non-alphabetic characters
    for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(sentence); i++) {
        if (iswalpha(sentence[i]) == 0) {
            wprintf(L"\n\"%lc\" %i\n", sentence[i], i);
            printf("An illegal character has been detected here");
            return (1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

And the testing:

```
Gimme a sentence:
hello world
Your sentence: hello world
Detecting non-alphabetic wide characters
"o " 2
An illegal character has been detected here
```

I'm also suspecting that iswalpha() is messing up too, but when i change "%[^\n]" to "%ls", although it doesn't accept spaces, which i want the program to accept them. Is there any way for it to accept spaces *and* also not input garbage?

Comment: Also, you cannot mix `printf` and `wprintf`.

Comment: Suggest `L"%[^\n]"` --> `L" %29l[^\n]"`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Re: [you cannot mix printf and wprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112697/wscanfl-n-is-inputting-garbage#comment96968016_55112697) --> interesting [LSNED](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LSNED)

Comment: @chux well you "can" but you need to call `fwide` all the time it seems... Oh no, you can't :D

Comment: @chux it is the footnote: "if the orientation has been determined, then `fwide` doesn't change it..." i.e. you need to call *freopen* all the time...

Comment: It would help to give details of compiler and environment; before this was added to the C Standard, implementations did their own thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things wrong.

- you cannot mix `printf` and `wprintf` on the same file, including `stdout` (except if you call `freopen` to change the orientation of the stream all the time...)
- missing `l` for `%l[^\n]`
- space is non-alphanumeric, that everything "worked" with the other specifier was due to the string not containing space...

Fixed code:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t sentence[30];
    wprintf(L"Gimme a sentence:\n");
    wscanf(L"%l29[^\n]", sentence); //Reading the line
    wprintf(L"Your sentence: %ls\n", sentence); //Printing the whole line

    wprintf(L"Detecting non-alphabetic wide characters"); //Detecting non-alphabetic characters
    for (int i = 0; sentence[i]; i++) {
        if (iswalpha(sentence[i]) == 0) {
            wprintf(L"\n\"%lc\" %i\n", sentence[i], i);
            wprintf(L"An illegal character has been detected here");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux `ENOCOFFE` ;)

Comment: It worked, didn't knew you had to only replace the s in "ls" instead of the whole thing and about not mixing printf with wprintf. Thanks!